# Is it possible to upload and extract a zip file to a given location using only HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, zip

I have a web page which asks users to select a zip file on their machine and upload it. It also asks for a destination on the server where the zip file should go. I want it to work in such a way that when they tell me where the file is on their machine and where it belongs on my server, then click "send," it should be sent to my server, placed in the designated directory, and unzipped.

I want to do this in just HTML and JavaScript. Is that possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: If you want to store the results in a folder on server side, this is not possible using pure JavaScript.

Comment: You cant upload a file with just JS, you need some server side programming as well, like PHP..!

Comment: You can't do this - and if you're wondering why, I recommend that you think about what a malware author would do if you *could* do this.

Comment: There are javascript unzipping tools, you'll need some server interaction just to store the files on the server.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this serverside; the client's browser cannot write to the file system of the server directly as it's a huge security risk.

In addition to that, not even HTML5 with it's File API can extract ZIP files. You need to do it on the server with PHP, or whatever language you're using.

If you just want to do things locally on the client, you could consider a Flash/Java/Browser extension, but I wouldn't recommend it for compatibility and performance reasons. Your best bet is to send a request to the server for it to process and send back. You're already serving the HTML page, so you can use the same server to process the ZIP file.

If, on the other hand, you want to write the ZIP file to the server, you *have* to do it server side for reasons stated in my first paragraph.

Comment: can i do it all on the client side itself? no interaction with the server end?

Comment: @dibya you mean, the target folder is on the user's drive as well? What sense would it make to unzip the file using a web page then, instead of a normal, local unzip app?

Comment: @JamWaffles - i just have to show a mock up which works on my local machine. Later on i have to extend it to the server side

Comment: @Pekka - hav to run this on a webpage as of now in the local system. its just a mock up. Later on i will have to extend this to the server side.

Comment: If you're going to extend it to a serverside process anyway, why not write the mockup so it does that? You should have a look at the [HTML 5 file API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Answer (score 0):

You can unzip/zip content within JavaScript using [rawdeflate](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate).

As other posters suggest, you cannot save directly to the local filesystem using a plain browser. You either need to echo the result back off the server (in which case it may as well unzip), or you can use Flash, for example, [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify), if it is installed.

Most modern browsers support [FileAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) for loading from the local filesystem, certainly, Chrome, Firefox and Opera do. I haven't tested IE 9.